# Android Compose Error for CoreTextField -> CoreTextField -> semanticsModifier

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I get the following error when switching from Fragment to Compose view and this is experienced by many users.
I couldn't solve the error because **I don't use TextField** within that page or any page it opens from the inside. I'm attaching the output I got from Firebase. All testers and I did not experience this problem. And this problem is the most common crash error in my application and it reduces my **crash free rate by 2-3%**.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method performImeAction$default(Lf2/b0;Ljava/lang/String;Lku/a;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Lf2/y; or its super classes (declaration of 'f2.y' appears in base.apk)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$semanticsModifier$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$semanticsModifier$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:2)
   at androidx.compose.ui.semantics.CoreSemanticsModifierNode.applySemantics(CoreSemanticsModifierNode.java:2)
   at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$collapsedSemantics$1.invoke(LayoutNode.java:12)
   at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$collapsedSemantics$1.invoke(LayoutNode.java:12)
```

build.gradle

```
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using such an old Compose BoM version?

Comment: @Edric i wanted to stay on a stable version and I don't have enough time to test everything when I upgrade to the new compose version.